# Get phone number as string from long string in c

Tags: c, substring

I have Telit modem, and i want to get the sim phone number, the Telit return string like:

```
"+CNUM: "","+123456789123456",**145**ok"

Or : "+CNUM: "","+123456789123456",**129**ok"
```

The different only with the numbers `145(International), 129(National)`.

I want to get only the number : +123456789123456, without  "+CNUM: ""," and without ,129.

I tried:

```
responseBuffer ="+CNUM: "",""+123456789123456"",145";
sscanf(responseBuffer,"%*s %s",phoneNum);   // cut the beginning
```

how do i get rid of the reset of the string, the characters from `','` to the end?

Comment: Can you please try to format the input string (the one you make `responseBuffer` point to) properly, because right not that will give you a compiler error.

Comment: what have you actually tried?

Comment: So `"+CNUM: ,+467190002574211,145"` really?

Comment: Have you tried [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) by the way?

Comment: @user5742600 If you need to have quotes inside string, use escape character! In this case there will be something like this: `"+CNUM: \"\",\"+123456789123456\",145ok"`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - No now i will try, thanks.

Comment: In the 2 examples the beginning is fixed so `char s[21]; if (1 == sscanf(responseBuffer,"\"+CNUM: \"\",\"%20s",phoneNum)) Success(phoneNum); `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JoachimPileborg i use strtok

```
responseBuffer ="+CNUM: "",""+123456789123456"",145";
token = strtok(responseBuffer, ",");
if( token != NULL ) 
  token = strtok(NULL, ",");
strcpy(phoneNum,token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a code which searches for '+' char and after finding it store telephone number in to a string pointer.

```
storePhoneNumber(const char* input, char* dest){
//loop over the input
//look for '+' char
//when found start to store numbers on by one
// put it in to the dest
}
```